# Can't use a custom element even if it is registered

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have to use a custom element in my project, and it used to work perfectly.
I am now changing the design of the project so I'm restarting it from zero, and now I can't use a custom component.

I haven't changed anything in the custom element itself.

Here is the code for hte page where i want to use the element:

```
<template >
<v-app>
<body>
  <v-img id="background" :src="images.background"></v-img>
  <v-img id="logo-transparent" :src="images.logoTransparent"></v-img>
  <DraggableDiv class="dragdiv">
    <template>

    </template>
  </DraggableDiv>
</body>
</v-app>
</template>
```

And here is the script part:

```
import DraggableDiv from '../components/DraggableDiv.vue'
export default {
  name: 'CreationCouches',
  data: () => ({
  components: {
    DraggableDiv,
    Palette
  }
})
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Hi, I think the problem is you have passed `components` in `data`.

Comment: Yes I just saw this, but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I was adding the component into the data() but it has to be outside of it:

```
import DraggableDiv from '../components/DraggableDiv.vue'
export default {
  name: 'CreationCouches',
  data: () => ({
     //some data
}),
  components: {
    DraggableDiv,
    Palette
  }
}
```